# preserving original folder structure when creating a project from original c++ code in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I create a project from existing c++ code with the folder structure

```
- src
  - subfolder1
     file1.h
     file1.cpp
     .
     .
     .
  - subfolder2
     file2.h
     file2.cpp
     .
     .
     .
  .
  .
```

The original file structure is lost in the solution explorer and all the source files are under "Source Files" while the header files are under "Header Files".

How can I create a project from existing code such that the original folder structure is reflected in the solution explorer?

Comment: How do you create the new project from the existing project?

Comment: File -> new -> project from existing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way files are shown in solution explorer by default are a projection and not the actual structure. Two possible solutions:

If you want to view the files as they are laid out on the file system you should turn on "Show All files" option on the solution explorer.

Drawbacks:

- This is a per project setting so you'll have to toggle it for all projects, and is not persisted in the solution files but in the temporary Visual Studio files, you'll have to repeat it when you open the project in a new place
- Temporary files that are of no interest for the project might show up in solution explorer

If you want, you could also organize the files in the solution with filters to match the layout on the disk (by hand, or if this is something you want to automate by writing a program to update the *.vcxproj.filter xml file). Big drawback:

- In this case would be that you'll have to remember to maintain this when you add new files.